# How to mock a constructor throwing an exception in Mockitio

Tags: java, mockito

I am trying to use Mockito to mock throwing an exception in a constructor. I would prefer not using PowerMock (I know how to do that). This is basically what I want to do, using Junit 5:

```
@Test
void exceptionAtConstruction() {
    final RuntimeException ex = new RuntimeException();
    try (MockedConstruction<SomeClass> mocked = 
        Mockito.mockConstruction(SomeClass.class))
    {
        when(??).thenThrow(ex);
        assertThrows(RuntimeException.class,()->new SomeClass());
    }
}
```

I have not been able to find out what to substitute for "??". The obvious would have been `mocked.constructed()`, but that turned out to be something entirely different.

The closest I have got so far is the workaround

```
@Test
void exceptionAtConstruction() {
    final RuntimeException ex = new RuntimeException();
    try (MockedConstruction<SomeClass> someMock =  mockConstruction(SomeClass.class,
        new MockedConstruction.MockInitializer<SomeClass>(){
            @Override
            public void prepare(SomeClass mocked,MockedConstruction.Context context){
                throw ex;
            }
        }))
    {
        assertThrows(RuntimeException.class,()->new SomeClass());
    }
}
```

Here I get an exception which has my expected exception as the second level cause.

Comment: Use a factory class with a `create` method which creates the object, and mock the factory in your tests.

Comment: What's the implementation of your constructor?

Comment: @knittl It is not my constructor. I want construction of some third party class to throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

> Don't mock a type you don't own! [[src]](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/How-to-write-good-tests#dont-mock-a-type-you-dont-own)

You are trying to mock the constructor of an external class. Instead, change your code to use a factory instead which calls the constructor. You can then easily stub the factory method to throw the exception.

So going from a direct constructor call:

```
class YourClass {
  method() {
    final SomeClass obj = new SomeClass();
    // ...
  }
}
```

refactor the code to create the instance via a factory. Java 8+ makes this an easy task by leveraging method refs and lambdas:

```
class YourClass {
  @VisibleForTesting
  Supplier<SomeClass> makeSomeClass = SomeClass::new;
  method() {
    final SomeClass obj = makeSomeClass.get();
    // ...
  }
}

class YourClassTest {
  @Test
  void test() {
    final YourClass yourObj = new YourClass();
    yourObj.makeSomeClass = () -> {
      throw new RuntimeException();
    };

    assertThatCode(() -> yourObj.method())
        .isInstanceOf(RuntimeException.class);
  }
}
```

You don't even need Mockito :)